# Read all received messages from a Warp WebSocket

Tags: rust, websocket, rust-tokio, warp

I am trying to create a game using WebSockets and am having difficulties understanding Streams. I know they are meant to be awaited asynchronously; however, I would like a different approach.

I have a game loop, which is spawned in its tokio task. At the beginning of every frame, the game loop should read all messages received from the WebSocket. I have yet to find out how I could do this without actively blocking the task until a message arrives. Moreover, I don't know how many messages there would be to read, as I want to read all messages received since the last frame.

I know I can read the messages from the WebSocket stream as shown below:

```
let (ws_sender, mut ws_rcv) = ws.split();
while let Some(result) = ws_rcv.next().await {
    // Handle result
}
```

My question is, if there is a way I could read the messages like this:

```
let (ws_sender, mut ws_rcv) = ws.split();
for result in ws_rcv.available_messages() {
    // Handle result
}
```

This approach would only read the values that have already been received and wouldn't block the thread.

Comment: The problem here is not the streams themselves. But how to discriminate which ones are from one frame or another. Does the messages have any kind of metadata attached for that? Otherwise I would say it is not possible.

Comment: If the messages are not specifically related to any frame, you can spawn a task that accumulates incoming messages into a buffer as they arrive, then you can process the messages that are in the buffer and clear the buffer on each iteration of your main loop.